# What does datetime.date + datetime.timedelta = datetime.date

Tags: python, datetime

When I run

```
from datetime import date, time, timedelta
date(2012, 11, 1) + timedelta(0, 3600)
```

The result is

```
datetime.date(2012, 11, 1)
```

In order to get the desired results I have to use combine i.e.

```
datetime.combine(date(2012, 11, 1), time(0,30))
```

Now that's not a big deal, but silently allowing a timedelta to be added to a date but then returning a date instead of a datetime resulted in a subtle bug which tool a while to track down. Surely it should either return a datetime or throw?

Edit: I've discovered that dateutil.relativedelta behaves as I expect i..e

```
datetime.date(2013,1,1)+dateutil.relativedelta(minutes=1)
>>datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 1)
```

This is a lot easier to use than datetime.combine with datetime.time or converting a date to a datetime in order to add a timedelta to it.

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: I don't have a "why", but I have a [documentation link](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#date-objects) specifying the behavior. Look at Supported operations, note 1, where it says `timedelta.seconds` and `timedelta.microseconds` are ignored. Personally, I think it would be cleaner to throw an exception on nonzero seconds or microseconds.

Comment: @Lego Stormtrooper I'd expect date+timedelta = datetime

Comment: As the answer indicates, you've expected wrong. A `date` has no time portion, so adding a `time` to a `date` gives the same original `date`. You need to use a `datetime` to add a date to it.

Comment: @user2357112 I'm not reading it like that, firstly under supported operations it says date2 = date1 + timedelta | date2 is timedelta.days days removed from date1. which doesn't make a lot of sense. Secondly it doesn't mention that hours or minutes are ignored, just seconds and milliseconds?

Comment: @user2981639: `timedelta` doesn't actually store hours or minutes. Those are converted to seconds, which are then ignored in the addition.

Comment: @user2357112 I see, that makes a bit more sense.

Comment: I think your key misunderstanding is that you expect the `date` object for 2014-01-05 to represent the time point 2014-01-05T00:00:00. If that were the case, then it would make sense that adding 15 minutes to it would give you the time point 2014-01-05T00:15:00—exactly analogous to adding `.5` to the integer `1` to get the float `1.5`. But that's _not_ what a `date` means. A `date` doesn't represent a timepoint, it represents the day as a whole. So adding 15 minutes to a date is meaningless.

Comment: … Which means you _could_ argue that Python should have a separate `datedelta` type, or that using a `timedelta` with sub-day values with a `date` should be an exception. The latter of those ideas might even get some traction on an appropriate forum, like the `python-ideas` list. (I suspect that ultimately the consensus would be to leave it alone for backward compatibility, but I could easily be wrong.) So, if you feel this is a problem with the language, bring it up where it can do some good rather than just implying that there's a problem in a question on StackOverflow.

Comment: @abarnert yes that's exactly how I was thinking. I defn do think that a seperate datedelta type is clearer, it was the fact that it allowed me to add a date and timedelta that made me assume that the result would be a datetime not a date. My expectation was either an exception or a datetime. I'm sure you're correct that it'll be rejected on the basis of backward compatibility

Comment: @user2981639: I wouldn't be _too_ sure. Yes, the seconds-ignoring behavior is documented, but if nobody can think of any reasonable code that would take advantage of it, it might make sense to change it to an exception. (Especially if there's going to be a major overhaul to `datetime` in 3.5 or 3.6 anyway, which has been suggested…) And if anyone _can_ think of reasonable code that would take advantage of the current behavior, wouldn't you rather see that example than try to guess whether one might exist?

Comment: @abarnet, thinking about it some more, yes I agree with you. x = y + z should imply z = x - y. In this case this only holds if the timedelta is (days, seconds=0, microseconds=0). So I think it would make sense to either return a datetime or throw an exception when attempting to add a timedelta to a date where seconds!=0 and microseconds!=0

Comment: Also the comment in datetime.py "Representation: (days, seconds, microseconds).  Why?  Because I felt like it." is a little unusual...

Comment: timedelta will happily convert `seconds > 86400` to days though when creating a new instance

Comment: Thanks @PeterGibson, that also applies if minutes > 60, hours > 100 etc. But the datetime.time class wont (as I'd expect, as it represents a time of day, not the difference between 1 datetimes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on Mark's answer, it makes no sense to add a `date` and `time` object together in *any semantic context*, so Python doesn't allow this.

- If I add 10 minutes to the date `2012-11-01` and I only want a date object, I still have `2012-11-01`.
- If I add 10 minutes , *360 times* to the date `2012-11-01` and I only want a date object after each iteration I would still have `2012-11-01`, so at the end I'd still have `2012-11-01`.
- Thus, If I add 3600 minutes to the date `2012-11-01` even though its a full day, if I only want a date object after each iteration I would still have `2012-11-01`.

You can use a `datetime` instead to add minutes to a "date" (not the commas, as a Python `date` object *does not have a time component*). However your initial object *will* have a minutes component, and the `datetime` object will be `2012-11-01 00:00:00`.

Comment: I agree that I should be using datetime in this instance.

Answer (score 3):

Python assumes you're smart enough to only use `timedelta` objects that refer to an integral number of days when you add to a `date` object, since you obviously don't care about the time component.

It would be surprising for addition to return a different type than either of the operands. You might think it's similar to `1 + 0.5` returning `1.5`, except that the result is the type of the second operand.

You would think there would be an easy way to convert from `date` to `datetime` but there doesn't appear to be. I can think of two ways:

```
dt = datetime.combine(d, time())

dt = datetime(d.year, d.month, d.day)
```

Once converted to a `datetime` you can easily add the `timedelta` to get what you expect.

P.S. I've found the best strategy is to pretend `datetime.date` and `datetime.time` don't exist and to use `datetime.datetime` exclusively. Lots less headaches that way.

Comment: That doesn't seem safe, when you add an int to a float you expect a float regardless of the order of the arguments as you don't want to lose digits to the right of the decimal point. I certainly don't think it's obvious that you don't care about time when adding time to a date?

Comment: @user2981639 it's obvious because you're using a representation that doesn't deal with time. Since Python has a `datetime` object they expect you to use that instead if time is significant.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like I need to convert the date to a datetime as above, then add the timespan. datetime.combine(date,time) doesn't really work in this instance as I want to add say 180 minutes to the date to get 01:30